# Video Conversion Automation

Tags: video, scripting, automation

Currently video recordings are being downloaded from a website (a third party software). The video download is in ARF Format and needs to be converted to MP4 in order to upload it our website. At the moment we have to manually download from the Website (using a URL), covert it and then upload. Wanted a way to automate this process so that the user can enter the URL and then the conversion and upload can take place automatically. What is the best way to achieve this so that a User Interface can be added aswell. 
I have looked up and found a way to do this using VB Scripting but in this case only the conversion part can be automated (i.e. it assumes that the videos have already been downloaded. 
Is it possible to program this on Java or is a Scripting language required?

Answer (score 0):

Anything you can do in a scripting language, you can do in java, and vice versa. In fact every turing complete language, by definition, is functionality equivalent to any other.

Comment: So based on this what would be your recommendation? Im not sure how I would be able to download videos (given a URL) using java code and make the conversion

Comment: If you don't already know how to do it programmatically, My recommendation is to hire a contractor to create this tool for you.

Comment: No contractor will be hired. Planning to do this myself. Planning on creating a web based application